# Alpine LinuxにおけるPython3での画像の類似性チェック

Tags: python, opencv, 画像

Pythonで二種類の写真(AとB)用意して、写真Aと写真Bの一部分を比較して、類似性が高かったら写真Bのその座標を返すというプログラムを作りたいのですが、OSの都合上OpenCVが使えなくて困っています。

OpenCVに代わる手段を教えてもらえると助かります。

追記
環境
OS:Alpine Linux(iSH)
Python:3.7.5
　
その他必要(そう)な情報がありましたら教えてもらえるとありがたいです

Comment: AlpineでもOpenCVをイチからビルドすれば使えそうな気がしました。あるいは容量の制限があるなどでしょうか。

Comment: コンパイル手段は考えてましたが、やり方が分かりづらいのと上記のことさえ出来ればOpenCVのような高度なライブラリは必ずしも必要とは感じなかったのでやってない感じです。あとiSHはiPhone用のアプリで、現状1、2GBほどしか割けないのでこれを超えるようだとコンパイルは不可能になっちゃいます。

Comment: この記事 [Python, OpenCV, NumPyで画像を比較（完全一致か判定、差分取得など）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-opencv-numpy-image-difference/) で、比較処理だけなら NumPy や Pillow が使えるとあります。

Comment: @kunif さん、その記事では写真 A と B 全体を比較していますが、今回比較したいのは A 全体と B の一部分であることには注意が必要そうです。また、写真の場合ノイズが乗るので単なるピクセル値の差分は殆ど役に立たなさそうです。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、OpenCVにこだわる意識を変える感じでコメントしたので、私も記事のプログラムが使えるとは思っていませんでしたが、かえって大きなお世話だったかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 1):

Pythonであれば[scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org)は有用です．簡単な画像処理であれば，関数として実装されていることが多い印象です．
自分は使ったことないですが，以下のように簡単なテンプレートマッチングであれば難しいコードを書かなくてもできるみたいです．

- https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_template.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48732991/search-for-all-templates-using-scikit-image

ただ，OpenCVにあってscikit-imageに無い機能は少なくないので，いざとなれば自前で実装をする必要がでてくると思います．そういったときにはNumPyやSciPyが便利そうです．